# Add new number from a list every time a function is repeated (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, pyautogui

I have this list:

```
list_vin = ['D03960','D03987','D04014']
```

This function which uses the list:

```
def lol():
    pyautogui.click(699,60)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command','f')
    pyautogui.typewrite(list_vin[2])
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command','p')
    pyautogui.press('enter')
lol()
```

And this function to repeat the list:

```
def refresh():
    schedule.every(int(1)).seconds.do(lol)
    while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
refresh()
```

How can I make it so that every time the function repeats a new item is used from the list? E.g. first time function runs it uses this D03960, second time the function runs it uses this D03987 in this line of the function `pyautogui.typewrite(list_vin[2])`

I am a beginner, don't be mad if I phrased the question incorrectly, hopefully, you understand it. Btw feel free to change the code entirely.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use **.pop()**

The pop() method returns the item present at the given index. This item is also removed from the list.

```
def lol():
    pyautogui.click(699,60)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command','f')
    pyautogui.typewrite(list_vin[2])
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command','p')
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    list_vin.pop()
lol()
```

So every time you run `lol()` your iterable `list_vin`will become "shorter"

Comment: Thank you mate, totally works but as @Josh mentioned I somehow need to account for the list ending.

Answer (score 1):

***Use a counter***

@chickenshifu's response is great but keep in mind that if you use pop, list_vin will eventually be empty. Be sure to account for that in your code.

If you didn't want the items from the list to be removed you could do the following:

```
iteration = 0 

def lol(index):
    pyautogui.click(699,60)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command','f')
    pyautogui.typewrite(list_vin[index])
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command','p')
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    iteration += 1 
lol(iteration)
```

My method tracks which item of list_vin you are using and grabs the item by the index. 'iteration' will increase by 1 at the end of the 'lol' function.

You know you will have reached the end of the list when `iteration` is equal to `len(list_vin)`.

Please let me know if you have any questions or if I need to clarify anything!

Comment: Thanks, mate. Unfortunately, I run into an issue which is: TypeError: lol() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index'. Do you have any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Sorry! Every time you run ``lol`` you need to run it like this lol(iteration). 

I'm not sure how your program is structured but, I recommend that you have `iteration=0` at the **global** level. 

If you're only running lol through refresh then do the following:

def refresh():
    schedule.every(int(1)).seconds.do(**lol(iteration)**)
    while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
refresh()

Notice how ``lol`` within ``refresh()`` is now  is ``lol(iteration)``.

LMK if any other errors or questions come up.